# Вывод на экран конкатенации элементов разных списков

Tags: python

На вход даются несколько списков:

```
auto = ['KIA', 'Volkswagen', 'Mitsubishi', 'Renault']
auto_model1 = ['Cerato', 'Sorento', 'C`eed', 'Carnival']
auto_model3 = ['Passat', 'Tiguan', 'Golf', 'Touran']
auto_model2 = ['Galant', 'Pajero', 'Colt', 'Grandis']
auto_model4 = ['Megan', 'Kaptur', 'Clio', 'C4 Picasso']
car_body = ['sedan', 'crossover', 'hatchback', 'minivan']
```

Необходимо на вывод получить следующее (пример для одной марки):

```
KIA Cerato --> sedan
KIA Sorento --> crossover
KIA C`eed --> hatchback
KIA Carnival --> minivan
```

Важно! Задание для новичков, т.е. совсем новичков.

1. Использовать можно только структуры данных: списки
2. Не использовать специальные библиотеки и модули.

Уже всю голову сломал. Не понимаю, как можно использовать циклы, но так, чтобы не перебирать все элементы списка. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если правильно понял, вы хотите получить это:

```
auto = ['KIA', 'Volkswagen', 'Mitsubishi', 'Renault']
auto_model1 = ['Cerato', 'Sorento', 'C`eed', 'Carnival']
auto_model2 = ['Passat', 'Tiguan', 'Golf', 'Touran']
auto_model3 = ['Galant', 'Pajero', 'Colt', 'Grandis']
auto_model4 = ['Megan', 'Kaptur', 'Clio', 'C4 Picasso']
car_body = ['sedan', 'crossover', 'hatchback', 'minivan']

model = [auto_model1, auto_model2, auto_model3, auto_model4]

for a in range(len(auto)):
    for b in range(len(car_body)):
        print(f'{auto[a]} {model[a][b]} --> {car_body[b]}')
    print('')
```

результат:

```
KIA Cerato --> sedan
KIA Sorento --> crossover
KIA C`eed --> hatchback
KIA Carnival --> minivan

Volkswagen Passat --> sedan
Volkswagen Tiguan --> crossover
Volkswagen Golf --> hatchback
Volkswagen Touran --> minivan

Mitsubishi Galant --> sedan
Mitsubishi Pajero --> crossover
Mitsubishi Colt --> hatchback
Mitsubishi Grandis --> minivan

Renault Megan --> sedan
Renault Kaptur --> crossover
Renault Clio --> hatchback
Renault C4 Picasso --> minivan
```

Comment: #sergfsm большущее спасибо! Все так просто. Что-то в голосве моей бардак, что я не смог догадаться, точнее ходил вокруг да около.

Answer (score 1):

вот это требовалось?

```
auto = ['KIA', 'Volkswagen', 'Mitsubishi', 'Renault']
auto_model1 = ['Cerato', 'Sorento', 'C`eed', 'Carnival']
auto_model3 = ['Passat', 'Tiguan', 'Golf', 'Touran']
auto_model2 = ['Galant', 'Pajero', 'Colt', 'Grandis']
auto_model4 = ['Megan', 'Kaptur', 'Clio', 'C4 Picasso']
car_body = ['sedan', 'crossover', 'hatchback', 'minivan']

text = "KIA C`eed"

models = [auto_model1, auto_model2, auto_model3, auto_model4]

components = text.split()

index_auto = auto.index(components[0])
index_model = models[index_auto].index(components[1])

body = car_body[index_model]

print(text, "-->", body)
```

ну и по хорошему надо проверку на `-1` при получении индексов поставить (ситуация, когда объект в списке не найден

Comment: Приветствую! Да, только для всех входящих структур. То есть для всех марок так должно выходить (KIA Sorento --> crossover, Volkswagen Tiguan --> crossover, Renault Megane --> sedan и т.д)